# Mudar view/componente mas não o URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Estou a trabalhar numa página 404, trabalha bem, eu tenho o seguinte:

```
const router = new VueRouter({ 
  routes: [
        // ... 
        {
            path: '*',
            component: NotFound,
            name: '404',
            meta: {page_title: '404 NOT FOUND'}
        },
    ]
});

// ... alguma coisa 'not found'

this.$router.push({name: '404'});
```

O problema disto é que o URL muda também, mas eu só quero que a view/componente mude, e o URL se mantenha.

Eu acho muito chato ser redirecionado para http://example.com/404, se me enganar em alguma coisa tenho de escrever o url todo ou ir pelo autofill do navegador, de qualquer maneira não gosto.

Eu estava a pensar se há algum método/lógica para que possa ter alguma coisa como https://www.facebook.com/sdfsd/sfsdf/asfasfsafastgtgregre.

Resumindo, quero que a view/componente mude mas não o URL, no caso de cair na rota configurada acima (404).

Há alguma maneira/built-in de fazer isto com vue/vue-router, ou um *workaround*?

Answer (score 2):

Também fiz [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101126/change-view-component-but-not-url) no SO en, e a resposta que obti foi esta, resulta, apesar de não saber se é 'bem feito':

```
let route = this.$router.match({ name: '404' });
this.$router.history.updateRoute(route);
```

Em vez de `this.$router.push({name: '404'});`

Answer (score 0):

coloca um preventdefault(), assim ele não vai fazer o redirect.